# Word for items in a person's pockets

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for the items that are found in one's pockets? Or more generally, on one's person. Examples include: wallets, keys, cell phones, pens.

Comment: "Pocket contents" is what I'd use.

Comment: 'miscellanea' is a possible.

Comment: There is no special word for such items - at least none that I'm aware of.

Comment: Perhaps my *precious*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"contents"** is the word you are looking for.

But if you include umbrellas, tablets, notebooks, or any other carry-on item, I would say **"personal belongings"**.

- At airport security checkpoints: "Sir, show us the **contents** of your pocket, please?"
- Leaving the airplane: "Make sure you are taking all your **personal belongings** with you."

Comment: "empty your pockets" or "remove any metal objects/items from your pockets" are the ones I hear most often.

Comment: At security checkpoints, I usually hear *contents of your pockets* as opposed to *pocket contents*, but for specific items found there, *pocket* is nearly always attributive: *pocket change*, *pocket litter*, *pocket lint*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the term, [*paraphernalia*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paraphernalia).  For example,

> The paraphernalia in his pockets was both bulky and cumbersome.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would use paraphernalia, miscellany, objects, items, possessions, effects, contents, or belongings.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers on StackExchange are expected to be definitive; your answer would be improved by explaining *why* you believe those terms would be appropriate, including suitable references and examples. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance on submitting good answers.